# Javascript ReactJs render multiple components in the same div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting up on ReactJs and I have 2 components snd a render call below:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

var Hello2 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello2 {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Is it posible to render both components in container?

I've tried:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  <Hello2 name="World2" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

But that didn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wrap these into a container, else not possible.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <Hello name="World" />
  <Hello2 name="World2" /> 
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: This didn't work either: ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <Hello name="World" />,
  <Hello2 name="World2" />,
  </div>
  document.getElementById('container')
);

Comment: Please remove the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can render only one component, if you want to render multiple then wrap them in a div or any other wrapper element, Use this code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     <Hello name="World" />
     <Hello2 name="World2" />
  </div>
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Or we can also make use of array here, but don't forget to assign keys. Like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  [
     <Hello name="World" key={0} />
     <Hello2 name="World2" key={1} />
  ]
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**Update:**

With React 16+, we can use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), benefit will be, it will not add any extra node in dom. Like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
     <Hello name="World" />
     <Hello2 name="World2" />
  </React.Fragment>
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your two components into another component without adding any DOM elements, since `React.Component.render()` can handle arrays (see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render).

```js
"use strict";
class Hello extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(React.createElement('div',null,`Hello ${this.props.name}`));
   }
}
class Hello2 extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(React.createElement('div',null,`Hello2 ${this.props.name}`));
   }
}
class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return([
           React.createElement(Hello, {name: "World", key: "one"}),
           React.createElement(Hello2, {name: "World", key: "two"})
        ]);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Container),document.getElementById('container'));
```